# Create custom Tabbar in Xamarin Forms using NaviagtionPages & Buttons added inside a ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create custom Tabbar in Xamarin Forms using NaviagtionPages & Buttons added inside a ContentPage.
I cannot use the default Tabbed Page because the UI shows up differently for Android and iOS with it (tabbar at top on android vs tabbar at bottom for iOS). 
Hence, I was creating a common component using Xamarin forms.
I have created a similar custom tabbar in iOS (by adding Navigation controllers as child controllers along with buttons in a View controller).

So far I have added Buttons and ContentPages(by ContentPage.Content) inside a ContentPage. I toggle the visibility of the content pages on tapped events of the buttons.

But I want to replace the ContentPages by NavigationPages so that each tab(button) can have its own stack of ContentPages.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to add NavigationPage inside a content view to make this work.

Comment: You can try with ScrollView with horizontal orientation.